# Can you `break` from multiple loops like PHP can by passing a number?

Tags: c, loops

If you are in a 3rd nested loop in PHP, you can do `break 3;` and break all loops up 3 levels.

`break` seems to work in C. But if I do `break 3` I get a syntax error. I guess it doesn't support it.

What is the best way to break multiple loops? Should I set a flag which is checked up the loops - and breaks if it is set?

Is there anything more elegant?

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo I reckon you should undelete your answer.  :)

Comment: In case Daniel Vassallo doesn't, the best part of his answer was:  [http://xkcd.com/292/](http://xkcd.com/292/)

Comment: Undeleted due to popular demand :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes goto is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 11):

You could use `goto`, but:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The usual solutions are:

- flags or other state checked in each of the nested loops
- `goto` a label after the end of the outer loop
- refactor your code so that the nested loops are in a function of their own. Use `return` to in effect break from the outermost loop.

Answer (score 5):

Another way besides `goto` is to use a shared variable in all of the conditional portions of the `for` loops.  This shared variable can be used like a kill switch for the loop.

```
bool done = false;
for (int i = 0; i < someNum && !done; i++ ) {
  for ( int j = 0; j < someOtherNum && !done; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < again && !done; i++ ) { 
      if ( someCondition ) { 
        done = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also agree.  goto has its uses and this is one of the main ones.

Answer (score 0):

Steve Jessop's answer arrived a few seconds before I was ready to post my answer.  I have one suggestion to add to his, although it may not be considered elegant - throw an exception.

Comment: @alex: <Sigh> Oh, this was C, wasn't it?  Technically I guess it doesn't currently have exceptions, but C++ does.  Google C and exceptions and you'll find some write ups on how to implement exceptions, e.g. this [Wikipedia write up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling_syntax#C).

Comment: Well, C may not have exceptions but C has `setjmp` and `longjmp`. Yep, you heard it here first. :-P (P.S. Any changes to your local variables might get undone, beware.)

Comment: @Chris: Wow, using `longjmp` to avoid a `goto` deserves some kind of award for Outstanding Dedication to Humorously Misunderstanding Dijkstra. Well done!